# java method overload inheritance and polymorphism

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, overloading

Here's a test practice question i came across, would appreciate your help in making me understand the concepts

Let Hawk be a subclass of Bird. Suppose some class has two overloaded methods void foo(Hawk 
h) and void foo(Bird b). Which version would get executed in the call foo(x) after the 
declaration Bird x = new Hawk();

Here's the code i have so far, could someone explain to me why foo(bird b) gets executed?

```
public class MPractice {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Bird x = new Hawk();
        Third y = new Third();
        y.foo(x);
    }

}



 public class Third {
    void foo(Hawk h) {
        System.out.println("Hawk");
    }
    void foo(Bird b) {
        System.out.println("Bird");
    }


}
```

Comment: No polymorphism involved here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Java performs overload resolution for choosing methods, it uses that type of the variable, not the runtime type of the object, to choose the method.  The type of `x` is `Bird`, so the `Third` method chosen is `foo(Bird)`.

This is because polymorphism isn't involved here; we're not calling a potentially overridden method on the `Bird` variable `x`, we're just calling one of a set of overloaded methods on an unrelated class, `Third`.

Answer (score 2):

At compile time, method invocation for overloaded methods is determined based on the type the method parameters and the compile time (or static) type of the method arguments.

In your case, `Third#foo(..)` can take a `Hawk` and it can take a `Bird`. In your invocation

```
y.foo(x);
```

the compile time (or static) type of the argument `x` is `Bird`, since that's how it's declared, so the `Third#foo(Bird)` method will be invoked.